# Mongoose - find documents based on array of objects field by partial matching another array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I`ll send to my api the following array format

`['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'kiwi', 'lemon']`

In my database, I have a collection called `Recipes` having the following field format

`ingredients: [ {
..,
name: 'apple',
..
}, {
..,
name: 'orange',
..
}]` - being an array of objects with this kind of format

Having the following documents in my DB:

Document #1

`ingredients:[
{.., name: 'apple', ..},
{.., name: 'kiwi', ..}, 
{.., name: 'banana', ..}]`

Document #2

`ingredients:[
{.., name: 'apple', ..},
{.., name: 'orange', ..}, 
{.., name: 'kiwi', ..}]`

Document #3

`ingredients:[
{.., name: 'lemon', ..},
{.., name: 'tomato', ..}, 
{.., name: 'potato', ..}]`

How the mongoose query should look like to return Document#2, Document#1, Document#3(this order as their arrays are the most similar to initial requested array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            totalMatch: {
                $size: {
                    $setIntersection: [['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'kiwi', 'lemon'], { $map: { input: "$ingredients", as: "ingredient", in: "$$ingredient.name" } }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            totalMatch: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            totalMatch: 0
        }
    }
])
```

All you need is to add additional field which counts all matching ingredients (using [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)) and then sort by that field in descending order. Since your ingredients contains objects you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to retrieve only names.

Comment: Looks good to me. And how to manage the case where initial sent array is empty? As I would like to not apply filtering at all if that`s the case

Comment: @AndreeaDumitru to clarify: you mean you don't want to get documents having empty ingredients array ?

Comment: I mean, instead of `['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'kiwi', 'lemon']` there s the possibility of an empty array `[]`. If that`s the case, I would like to check somehow on the start at the query and eventually skip the filtering if true

Comment: But then you don't need aggregation, you can just use `db.collection.find()`